# ¿Cómo funciona la alineación horizontal y vertical en las cajas flexibles?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3, flexbox

### CONTEXTO:

En el contenedor flexible tenemos dos ejes, el eje principal y el eje transversal:

[image: Ejes del contenedor flexible]

### PREGUNTAS:

*¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje horizontal?*

*¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje vertical?*

*¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en ambos ejes a la vez?*

*¿Qué sucede cuando cambio la dirección del contenedor flexible utilizando la propiedad `flex-direction`?*

*¿Cómo es posible alinear solamente un elemento a la izquierda y los demás a la derecha si no existe la propiedad `justify-self` o `justify-items` en el eje principal?*

**Nota:**

Esta pregunta está basada en **[esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609)**, a modo pregunta y respuesta, con el objetivo de ayudar a la comunidad de StackOverflow en español a entender un poco mejor las cajas flexibles y la alineación de los elementos flexibles.

Answer (score 7):

Como se ilustra en la pregunta, en las cajas flexibles tenemos dos ejes, el principal *(main axis)* y el transversal *(cross axis)*.

---

Para alinear los elementos flexibles en el **eje principal** tenemos la propiedad:

- [**`justify-content`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)

Para alinear los elementos flexibles en el **eje transversal** tenemos tres propiedades:

- [**`align-content`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
- [**`align-items`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
- [**`align-self`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)

  ---

Comencemos con la pregunta que dice así:

> *¿Qué sucede cuando cambio la dirección del contenedor flexible utilizando la propiedad `flex-direction`?*

Primero que nada es importante tener claro que las cajas flexibles o `flexbox` tiene como propósito el diseño (layout) en **una sola dimensión**.

*¿Qué quiere decir esto?*

La dirección del contenedor flexible puede ser de fila **o** de columna, no ambas al mismo tiempo.

La propiedad [`flex-direction`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property) acepta cuatro valores:

- [**`row`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-row)
- [**`row-reverse`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-row-reverse)
- [**`column`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-row-reverse)
- [**`column-reverse`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-column-reverse)

Cuando `flex-direction` tiene como valor `row` o `row-reverse` el eje principal es el horizontal y el eje transversal es el vertical.

Mientras que cuando `flex-direction` tiene como valor `column` o `column-reverse` el eje principal es el vertical y el eje transversal es el horizontal.

*Esto se debe a que:*

> El eje transversal es un eje corporal perpendicular a la dimensión
>   mayor de un cuerpo o bien a la dirección habitual de movimiento.

En resumen y volviendo a la pregunta:

> *¿Qué sucede cuando cambio la dirección del contenedor flexible utilizando la propiedad `flex-direction`?*

Se invierte el eje principal y el eje transversal si se cambia la dirección de fila a columna, o viceversa.

Pensémoslo así:

- Dirección en fila

[image: fila]

- Dirección en columna

[image: columna]

---

Teniendo un poco más claro esto, volvamos a redactar las preguntas que dicen así:

> ¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje horizontal?
>
> ¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje vertical?

Ya sabemos que la dirección afecta los ejes del contenedor flexible y los métodos de alineación se invierten, entonces las preguntas adecuadas son:

- ¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje principal?
- ¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje
  transversal?

---

## Métodos para alinear en el eje principal:

Según la **[W3C](https://www.w3.org/)** hay dos métodos para alinear los elementos flexibles en el eje principal:

1. La propiedad `justify-content`
2. [`auto` márgenes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

---

### justify-content

La propiedad [`justify-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) alinea los elementos flexibles del contenedor flexible en el eje principal.

Esta propiedad se define en el contenedor flexible pero solamente afecta a los elementos flexibles.

Existen cinco alineaciones que acepta esta propiedad:

- **flex-start** - Los elementos flexibles se agrupan al inicio del contenedor flexible.

*Sintaxis*: `justify-content: flex-start;`

[image: flex-start]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;  /* Valor inicial */
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- **flex-end** - Los elementos flexibles se agrupan al final del contenedor flexible.

*Sintaxis*: `justify-content: flex-end;`

[image: flex-end]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- **center** - Los elementos flexibles se agrupo al centro del contenedor flexible.

*Sintaxis*: `justify-content: center;`

[image: center]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- **space-around** - Los elementos flexibles se distribuyen uniformemente en el contenedor flexible.

*Sintaxis*: `justify-content: space-around;`

[image: space-around]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- **space-between** - Los elementos flexibles se distribuyen uniformemente en el contenedor flexible. A diferencia de `space-around`, el primer elemento flexible se alinea a un extremo y el último elemento flexible al extremo opuesto.

*Sintaxis*: `justify-content: space-between;`

[image: space-between]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

***En resumen***:

[image: justify-content resumen]

---

### Auto Márgenes

A diferencia de la propiedad `justify-content`, **los auto márgenes se definen en los elementos flexibles** en lugar del contenedor flexible.

Con ellos podemos lograr alineaciones que de algún modo sustituyen la inexistencia de propiedades como `justify-self` y `justify-items`.

Aquí podemos cubrir la pregunta:

> *¿Cómo es posible alinear solamente un elemento a la izquierda y los demás a la derecha si no existe la propiedad `justify-self` o
>   `justify-items` en el eje principal?*

Para esto esperaríamos que existiera `justify-self: flex-start;` y utilizarlo en el primer elemento, mientras que en el resto aplicaría `justify-content: flex-end;

Lamentablemente la propiedad `justify-self` no existe, pero hay una teoría de **[Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b)**, un gran contribuyente en StackOverflow en Inglés de las cajas flexibles (y de quien está basada esta respuesta, referencia **[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609)**), de que para esto están los auto márgenes.

```
.flex-item:first-child { margin-right: auto; }
```

[image: auto margen]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

O también:

```
.flex-item:nth-child(2) { margin-left: auto; }
```

[image: auto - margen]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

Cambiemos la dirección a columna y apliquemos un margen inferior con valor auto.

[image: margin-bottom auto]

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/eaco0Lyz/)

Este caso y muchos otros se pueden lograr con los auto márgenes.

---

## Métodos para alinear en el eje transversal:

---

### align-content

La propiedad [`align-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property) alinea los elementos similar a `justify-content` pero en el eje transversal.

Esta propiedad también se define en el contenedor flexible pero únicamente afecta a los elementos flexibles. Se requiere que exista más de una línea de elementos flexibles para que su efecto sea visible.

Existen 6 alineaciones que acepta esta propiedad. Todos los valores se comportan igual solo que en el eje transversal. El único valor adicional es `stretch`.

- [`flex-start`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-flex-start)

Sintaxis: `align-content: flex-start;`

[image: align content flex start]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`flex-end`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-flex-end)

Sintaxis: `align-content: flex-end;`

[image: align content flex end]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`center`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-center)

Sintaxis: `align-content: center;`

[image: center]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`space-between`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-space-between)

Sintaxis: `align-content: space-between;`

[image: align space between]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`space-around`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-space-around)

Sintaxis: `align-content: space-around;`

[image: align content space around]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`stretch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-content-stretch)

Sintaxis: `align-content: stretch;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

### align-items y align-self

La propiedad [`align-items`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property) alinea **todos** los elementos flexibles del contenedor flexible en el eje transversal.

Esta propiedad se define en el contenedor flexible pero solamente afecta a los elementos flexibles.

La propiedad [`align-self`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self) es muy similar a `align-items` a diferencia que esta alinea **un solo** elemento flexible del contenedor flexible en el eje transversal.

**IMPORTANTE:** Esta propiedad es diferente a las demás ya que se define en el elemento flexible y no en el contenedor flexible.

Existen cinco alineaciones que aceptan estas propiedades (en los demos se utilizará `align-items` por motivos de brevedad):

- [`flex-start`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-flex-start)

Sintaxis: `align-items: flex-start;`

[image: align items flex start]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`flex-end`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-flex-end)

Sintaxis: `align-items: flex-end;`

[image: align items flex end]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`center`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center)

Sintaxis: `align-items: center;`

[image: align items center]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`baseline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center)

Sintaxis: `align-items: baseline;`

[image: align items baseline]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even)::after {
  font-size: 8em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

- [`stretch`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center)

Sintaxis: `align-items: stretch;`

[image: align items stretch]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  border: .4em solid peachpuff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo es posible alinear los elementos flexibles en ambos ejes a la
>   vez?

Utilizando las propiedades `justify-content` y `align-items`, ambas con el valor `center`.

```
.contenedor-flexible {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image: center center]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

O con auto márgenes, utilizando únicamente una propiedad en el elemento flexible:

```
.elemento-flexible{
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: auto;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```